# browser extension recommendation for low speed high latency service

Tags: web-browser, monitoring, network

I'm on a satellite link.  The minimum latency for a round trip packet is 700 ms.  I've seen it take as much as 10,000 ms.

If I have a single browser window open and type 1 character into a search field, I get a rash of packets running back and forth between my machine and the search engine.

In the Bad Old Days of using teletype terminals (now you know how old I am...) you could put the terminal into 'line mode' where it wouldn't send the line until you hit carriage return/line feed.

I'm looking for a browser/extension combination that will:

1. Where possible block together multiple keystrokes and send them in a single packet.
2. Block all tracking packets.  (I already run no-script on a pretty short leash.)
3. Show a traffic flow by tab.

The first would decrease the per keystroke problem.

Second  saves

- A dns lookup
- An HTTP tcp setup
- An http get
- An http tcp teardown
  (Above assumes a new site for each tracker)

Number 3  gives you a quick show of which tab is being a bandwidth pig.  Ideally it would report much like multi router traffic grapher.

One user suggested Lynx.  Lynx was a PITA at the best of times.  I'd hate to use lynx with 30 tabs open.  (Or 30 terminal windows open.)

Comment: I wonder if there is a good combination of lynx out here that would assist under these network constraints. Much engineering was done back when baud were common, but these days bloat is out of hand for links that laggy due to physical constraints.

Comment: The "single keystroke" indicates you use Google *with* JS? With that delay c&paste your input might be a viable option? Please indicate whether this is for general use or in text input interactive scenarios? Pure bandwidth saving is easier than granularity for scripts…

Comment: As as workaround, type the _search string_ in e.g. TextEdit, then copy and paste it into the Search field in the browser.